# pandas dataframe indexing KeyError: 'Release Date'

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe

The purpose of this code is to scrape a bunch of data tables, turn them into pandas data frames, remove some unnecessary columns , fix the date then concatenate them in a single unified data frame and make the “Release date” data frame as index for the unified data frame.

All the above works ok except the indexing thing.

Here is data sample:

Release Date  U.S. 52-Week Bill Auction Turkey Gross Domestic Product (GDP) YoY

2018-06-19 18:30:00+02:00                    2.275%                                     NaN

2018-07-17 18:30:00+02:00                    2.335%                                     NaN

2018-08-14 18:30:00+02:00                    2.365%                                     NaN

2018-09-10 10:00:00+02:00                       NaN                                    5.2%

2018-09-11 18:30:00+02:00                    2.465%                                     NaN

2018-10-09 18:30:00+02:00                                                               NaN

Here is code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone


class DataEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = open(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\sample.txt").readlines()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Projects\Tutorial\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def title(self):
        names = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            title = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftColumn"]/h1').text
            names.append(title)
        return names

    def table(self):
        DataFrames = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            while True:
                try:
                    item = self.wait.until(
                        ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"showMoreHistory")]/a')))
                    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
                except Exception:
                    break

            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'])
            pos = 0
            for table in self.wait.until(
                    ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"eventHistoryTable")]//tr'))):
                data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td]")]
                if data:
                    df.loc[pos] = data[0:5]
                    pos += 1
            df = df.head(10)
            DataFrames.append(df)
        return DataFrames

    def date(self):

        dfs = []
        tables = self.table()
        for df in tables:
            Dates = []
            df["Date"] = df["Release Date"].apply(lambda date: date[:12]) + " " + df["Time"]
            for date in df["Date"]:
                date = datetime.strptime(date.strip(), '%b %d, %Y %H:%M')
                Dates.append(date)
            df["Date"] = Dates
            df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.tz_localize('EST').dt.tz_convert(get_localzone())
            df = df[['Date', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous', 'Release Date', 'Time']]
            df = df.drop(df.columns[-4:], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

            dfs.append(df)



        return dfs

    def rename(self):
        FinalDataFrames = []
        tables = self.date()
        names = self.title()
        for name, table in zip(names, tables):
            table.rename(columns={'Date': 'Release Date', 'Actual': name}, inplace=True)
            table['Release Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Release Date'])
            table = table.set_index('Release Date')
            FinalDataFrames.append(table)

        return FinalDataFrames

    def finalDF(self):
        dfs = self.rename()
        df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer', sort=True)
        df = df.set_index('Release Date', inplace=True)
        print(df)
```

Here is the error:

```
eTraceback (most recent call last):

 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in 

 pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in 

  pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in 

  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in 

  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  KeyError: 'Release Date'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/database.py", line 96, in <module>
    DataEngine().finalDF()

  File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/database.py", line 85, in finalDF
  df = df.set_index('Release Date', inplace=True)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
   packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 
  3909, in set_index

  level = frame[col]._values

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__

  return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column

  return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache

  values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
   packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get

  loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc

  return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in 
  pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in 
  pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in 
  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in 
  pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  KeyError: 'Release Date'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set the index in `rename()` (which removes the `Release Date` column), so when you try to set the index in `finalDF()` again pandas cannot find the `Release Date` column and throws an exception.

Note:
`df = df.set_index('Release Date', inplace=True)` sets the index in-place, so `df` will be `None` after the line is executed. Either remove `inplace=True` or do not do the variable assignment.